# Mercurial plug-in для Visual Studio 2010

Tags: mercurial, visual-studio, c#

Беглый поиск нашел несколько разных вариантов, тестировать различные плагины времени нет, да и отсутствие опыта работы с мерком вряд ли позволит сразу определить + и - разных программ. Посоветуйте хорошую и простую программу для работы с mercurial, интеграция со студей крайне желательна.

Comment: файл .hgignore удалось создать посредством echo "helllo" > .hgignore. Через ГУИ никак не хотело =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для себя выбрал [HgSccPackage](https://bitbucket.org/zzsergant/hgsccpackage/wiki/Home), кто что думает про этот плагин?

Comment: Использую уже месяц, довольно удобный плагин, все свои задачи выполняет на отлично, крайне советую!

Answer (score 3):

[VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/)

Comment: я ставил несколько, но не могу разобраться как делать коммит или пуш... я вообще не вижу их в студии...

Comment: Панель инструментов VisualHg надо добавить в toolstrip VS2010. Выглядеть будет вот так примерно: http://visualhg.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: уже разобрался, спасибо.